# How to using the "for" loop in python make the output print in one line

Tags: python, string

I have a simple bit of code what using the loop "for" prints out all the leters from input. It looks something like this:

```
    word = str(input('Word here:'))
    for i in range(0, len(word), 1):
    print(word[i])
```

I would really like sme help

Comment: You don't need a for loop: `print(word)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can *end* keyword in print statement to remove the newline character.

print(word[i],end=" ")